# Easiest way to use database between two software

Tags: python, database

fellows! I hope you are doing fine these days.
Currently I am working on a project at work, whose final goal is to create an interface between 2 pieces of software (I cannot mention which software, as it is a research project). The steps are as follows:

1. There are 2 software which provide data about processes.
2. The goal is: when the data changes in the first software, the data corresponding to the same process should also change in the second software.
   The data can be exported as Excel files or I can obtain it using Python (with scripts created by us). The leaders of the project proposed us to create a data base where we will store the data and compare the data from the two software in order to change it.
   My question is: how it is the easiest way to do it and which database software is more suitable? Currently, I am used to work with Python, but I do not mind inserting the Excel files directly in the database.
   Thank you in advance! I wish you a nice day, folks!

Comment: Isn't it better to do it via database replications?

Comment: You are asking us to compare apples and oranges... Python is a programming language that does has interfaces for database management and Excel files handling, Excel is a nice spreadsheet software, but Excel files are binary proprietary files. And in the end there is a database. I may need a strong coffee, but I cannot understand how Python, Excel, and the database should be related...

Comment: This question is maybe too general for this site. You might need a database server both client apps can connect to.

Comment: A context element that could matter here, is whether all this should occur in real time (delay < 1 second), dayly batches (once a day), or somewhere in between. It should have a huge impact on which solution will fit the requirement...